# In JQuery, how can I make dynamically generated jquery dialog that can be dropped into each other?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have some dynamically generated jquery dialogs that can be dragged, dropped, and resized.  I would like to be able to drop them into each other. So that when you move the parent, the object inside moves with it.  And if I close out the parent dialog, the children close too.  I am not sure how to accomplish that.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Here is the link to a fiddle I set up.  It does what I want; although it is sluggish and not dynamic.  I guess my problem now is making the entire thing dynamic.  How do I determine what the name of the object is that I am dragging and the name of the object I am dropping to is?

```
.appendTo is what I need right?  but how to grab the names?
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Bladetrick/DGbT3/780/

Comment: While this is a good question it's still very vague.  Can we get a little more information, maybe a demo or example?  maybe some code?

Comment: dialogs are appended to `body` element so dropping them on each other would likely be better managed with your own widget. Rewriting the dialog plugin would be a pain. You could still use jQueryUI styling so they look like dialogs. See the sortable/portlets example of widgets with UI styling that aren't really jQuery UI widgets

Comment: JMax - I have gotten as far as generating the dialogs dynamically. But haven't been able to drop them IN each other.

Comment: ntg - i will try to put something up on fiddler after a while but basically every time i click a button, i generate a new dialog.  i want to be able to drag those dialogs into each other so the dragged one becomes the child of whatever dialog it was dragged into.

Comment: Charlie - I don't absolutely need a dialog plugin.  actually a plain old div box would be cool.  i've looked around but haven't been able to find anything similar to what i want yet.  i'll have to reword my searches or something, i guess

Comment: Link to the fiddle is above in the post now, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to drag and drop one dialog into another. Check this [JQFAQ.com](http://jqfaq.com/how-to-enable-droppable-in-jquery-ui-dialog-box/) topic, i think this will be helpful to you.

Comment: this is excellent! i'll muck with it and see if i can get it to work with dynamically generated dialogs.  Thanks!